# For translations, can I use both xlf and yml files at the same time?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

My project has translations (xlf) files located in the `translations` directory, and they are properly detected.
I am using a vendor bundle in which the translation (yml) files which are located in its `Resources/translations` directory. So, thinking that I could reuse those translations, I added `{% trans_default_domain 'SchebTwoFactorBundle' %}` to my twig, but the Symfony toolbar says:

> These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be
>   found in the fallback locales. Add them to the translation catalogue
>   to avoid Symfony outputting untranslated contents.

```
Locale  Domain  Times used  Message ID  Message Preview
en  SchebTwoFactorBundle    1   scheb_two_factor.auth_code  scheb_two_factor.auth_code
en  SchebTwoFactorBundle    1   scheb_two_factor.login  scheb_two_factor.login
en  SchebTwoFactorBundle    1   scheb_two_factor.cancel scheb_two_factor.cancel
en  SchebTwoFactorBundle    1   label.copyright label.copyright
en  SchebTwoFactorBundle    1   label.security  label.security
```

Is this issue caused by the fact that I'm using **xlf** but the bundle is using **yml** ?

If it is, I'm planning just to convert all those **yml** files to **xlf**, and then put them in my own translations directory.

Comment: Did you check for the fallback locale configuration? See here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#configuration

Comment: Yes. The fallback (en) and other translation files from my "own" project works.